# R chunk within markdown extension

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am trying to write a markdown document where I have a chunk of R code within a theorem or example extension.

I assumed I could simply write the theorem extension, starting and ending with ``` and within define an R code chunk starting with ```{r} and ending with ```. As follows:

````
```{theorem, name="Test"}

Some initial text.


```{r}
a <- 1 + 1
print(a)
````

And some more text.

However, it seems markdown gets confused, as does stackoverflow, by closing the theorem chunk using the end of the R code block instead of nesting the blocks. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest chunks like that in r-markdown.  You'll need to close your first chunk then open a new one for the R chunk.

Comment: If you need to show code without running it, add `eval = FALSE` and `echo = TRUE` to the code chunk header.